# How to make one class have two names?

Tags: c++

I'm using a library that has only one difference between platforms/versions. One version calls the class btCollisionObject and other versions call it btCollisionObjectWrapper. If I could make this class have two names that still reference that class then all my problems would be solved. I tried: `#define btCollisionObject btCollisionObjectWrapper;` but it is not working. What is the correct way to give a class two names after the class has been defined?

Comment: Could that be because you have a semicolon in your #define, which (most likely) shouldn't be there?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe

```
typedef btCollisionObjectWrapper btCollisionObject;
```

Better to do it using language tools instead of the preprocessor.

Comment: error C2371: 'btCollisionObjectWrapper' : redefinition; different basic types

Comment: @SteveDeFacto Why are you using both versions of the library at the same time?

Comment: @SteveDeFacto: I guess you meant to do it the other way then?

Comment: @sftrabbit I'm not using both versions of the same library but I think it is also defining btCollisionObject but differently in this version. I'm going to try creating a third class and use a ifdef to figure out which is defined. Either way K-ballo's answer was the solution.

Comment: I think "preprocessor" is part of the C++ language, so telling "better use language tools instead of the preprocessor" is senseless. However, preprocessor `#define`s can do a lot of bad things. So what you are trying to say is that `typedef`s are better than `#define`s. Both are language tools.

Comment: @leemes: Technically, it isn't part of neither C nor C++ languages. That's why its a **pre** processor...

Comment: So you want to tell me that the `#...` syntax isn't **part of** C? (I'm not sure, so I don't want to provoke you in any way but want to get it right ;))

Comment: @leemes: Now I haven't said that, I said it isn't part of the **C language**. Keep in mind how the _preprocessor_ knows nothing at all about the **C** language, and it operates on mere tokens. Check out the _preprocessor_ sections at the **C** reference and you'll see what I mean...

Comment: @K-ballo Ok I think we are about to discuss about the definition of the preprocessor, which should not be the topic here. You wanted to tell that typedefs are better than defines, that's the point (I totally agree). We're about to get lost in details here...

Comment: I'm still unable to figure out how to get this to work. I need to check if a class is defined before using the typedef or I get the error I posted above. I tried this:

#ifndef btCollisionObjectWrapper
typedef btCollisionObject btCollisionObjectWrapper;
#endif

But ifdef can't detect if a class is defined. How can I check if btCollisionObjectWrapper is defined and if it is not then I use the typedef?

I was thinking maybe a try catch or something?

Comment: @SteveDeFacto: `#ifndef` is a preprocessor tool, it doesn't work with classes. You can't do that check; you will have to check for whatever situation leaves for the typedef not being there

Comment: @SteveDeFacto, I think we both missed the actual problem you were having in that on one platform you had one type, and on the other platform you had another. This meant that no matter what order the typedef was defined, on one of the platforms it would tell you it was already defined. I have adjusted my answer to what I hope is a more appropriate solution.

Comment: I just had to go back and get the same revision that was used on linux and compile it for windows. It's unfortunate that I have to make my library incomparable with newer versions of the library over something so small but any other solution I could think of would be a mess.

Answer (score 7):

If I understand your problem correctly you will have to find a way of determining which platform you are compiling for, because I don't know which platforms you are using I can't give any advice on this however it is probably possible to do so via macros.

The solution to your problem will probably look a bit like this.

In C++98 using a **type declaration**

```
#ifdef __PLATFORM_SPECIFIC_DEFINE
    typedef btCollisionObjectWrapper btCollisionObject;
#endif
```

In C++11 using an **alias declaration**, this has the added advantage that they may be used with templates however in your case you could get away with a simple typedef.

```
#ifdef __PLATFORM_SPECIFIC_DEFINE
    using btCollisionObject = btCollisionObjectWrapper;
#endif
```

This will allow you to use `btCollisionObject` as the class name for the platform that uses `btCollisionObjectWrapper`

You will of course have to replace the `__PLATFORM_SPECIFIC_DEFINE` with a macro that is defined by the platform that uses `btCollisionObjectWrapper`.

Comment: type aliases also have the advantage of being more 'C++-like' in that they emphasize types as opposed to expressions the way the C declaration syntax emphasizes expressions.

Comment: I want to know exactly what's the difference between a `typedef` and a `using` statement. Can you please point me to a website / whatever, which explains the difference? A google search expression leading to the correct result will also do it.

Comment: I'm not 100% on all of the differences as I haven't really looked into it myself, the only difference mentioned on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef) where I first learned of the `alias declaration` is that it may be used when creating an alias of a template.

Comment: @ctor I think I got it. However, I think I have to look at this tomorrow again. ;) "used within templates" seems to be slightly wrong to me. I think you wanted to say "can be used for templated types" instead. But as I said, I have to have a second look at it before commenting seriously.

Comment: I mean, if I want to alias `std::vector` to just `v` I can't use `typedef vector v`. However, I can use `template<class T> using v<T> = vector<T>`.

Comment: Unfortunately this will cause a redefinition error if someone tries to forward declare an `class btCollisionObject` somewhere